# Azure AD Graph API 400 Bad Request and 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I get a **400 Bad Request** with this code:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer **my-access-token-here**")
Dim groupsResponse As String = client.UploadString("https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups", "api-version=1.6")
```

I get a **401 Unauthorized** with this code:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer **my-access-token-here**")
Dim groupsResponse As String = client.DownloadString("https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.6")
```

I'm getting my accesstoken from this OAuth2 endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/**my-tentant-id-here**/oauth2/token
```

Where it says "myorganization" I also tried it with my tenant id in place of "myorganization".  With the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The **400** error is because you were trying to post the incorrect data format(string) to the wrong REST API endpoint.

If you want to request the groups, you can refer the REST below(refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations)):

```
get: https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/groups?api-version=1.6
```

For the **401** error, you may show the detail error message so that we can identity the root reason. And you can also parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/) to verify whether the `aud` claim is `https://graph.windows.net` and is there enough permission to call the Group REST like `Group.Read.All`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.Read.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: @Fei-Xue-MSFT per the original post, i also tried https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/groups?api-version=1.6 and got the same 400 error

Comment: @Fei-Xue-MSFT my token has a scope of Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.Read

Comment: The 400 error is caused by using `Post`, modify the endpoint URL will not fix this issue. Please use the `Get` method.